# iPhone 4 augmented reality with iOS5 which sensors to use?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm thinking of creating an augmented reality game using gps, camera and iPhone sensors. The main objective of the game is to be able to walk around billboards placed according to their gps coordinates. The player must be able to walk around the augmented reality billboard, which may be within 30-50 feet of the user. The game is played outdoors

I'm trying to understand what are the optimal sensors that I need to use to calculate the position and orientation in space.

Is it accelerometer +gyroscope within some
Reference frame, along with a core location from gps? Or is doing so redundant?

Alternatively, it would be nice to know if I can even hope to achieve enough accuracy to be able to walk around points

Update: I found this app: QuickDistance, which uses known eye level height to estimate distance to an object at the user's feet. Something tells me that the same concept can be used to more precisely find the local position of the user to improve GPS accuracy by finding the distance to known points. I'm not sure if there are any open source pedometer/distance calculators that use accelerometer, I'd love to know the kind of accuracy that can be obtained from those.

If All I can expect is a 56 feet accuracy outdoors, this means that my billboards would have to be huge.

PS. I Also noticed an incredible battery drain while using metaio SDK for AR, I'm not sure if what I'm describing is even feasible from the battery life point of view - running accelerometer, gyroscope, magnetometer and receiving constant GPS updates may kill the battery very fast. This is another reason why I want to understand how to keep track of the location with minimum number of sensors involved.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I fully understand, but you should use GSP to get lat long information. Attempting to use the sensors to create a dead reckoning location system would likely be fairly error prone. The GPS reports accuracy. I think the best you will is is ~9 meters but I doubt that would be that often.  Average accuracy (assuming outside without trees) something like 17 meters (56').

So you can walk around points. But you will need to draw a 56' or larger circle around each point and assume the user is somewhere inside of that area.

You could try to use dead reckoning but dead reckoning + AR feels like a game that will never play correctly to me. That's too much difficult to control tech.

I'd simplify your game and go out and test some readings asap to make sure what you are thinking about is sane.  It may very well not be. :)

Comment: Thanks, this is the kind of information that I was looking for. I can routinely see 9 meter/30 ft accuracy outdoors with clear sky, once I saw 3meters/10ft. This is the first time I hear about dead reckoning, I'll investigate that, as it sounds like the tech I'll have to use.

Answer (score 1):

Look at ChattAR - http://quickblox.com/developers/Chattar , it uses gps, camera and iPhone sensors (compas)

ChattAR is

1. an app;
2. a code sample;
3. a free and open technology which bring
   social interaction through Augmented Reality into your apps.

You can develop your own application using ChattAR code - it's free, you can download it from GitHub https://github.com/QuickBlox/ChattAR-ios

Also you can download ChattAR from itunes - it's free http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/chattar-for-facebook/id543208565?mt=8